# How to get image component from blueprint in c++

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

I have a dialog screenwith character icon and I need to be able to set up this image in code. But I don't know how to access this Image component (I put material instances in it).

**.h**

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> widgetDialogBottom;
UUserWidget* widgetDialogBottomInstance;
```

**.cpp**

```
widgetDialogBottomInstance = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(GetWorld(), widgetDialogBottom);
widgetDialogBottomInstance->Image("mi_dialog_2"); // Need something like this
widgetDialogBottomInstance->AddToViewport();
```

[image]

[image]

I made a class DialogBottomWidget:

**.h**

```
UCLASS()
class HOME_API UDialogBottomWidget : public UUserWidget 
{ 
        GENERATED_BODY()

    public: 
        void SetImage(UTexture2D* InTexture);

    private: 
        UPROPERTY(meta = (BindWidget)) UImage* CharacterPreview;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "DialogBottomWidget.h"

void UDialogBottomWidget::SetImage(UTexture2D* InTexture)
{
    CharacterPreview->SetBrushFromTexture(InTexture);
}
```

.. and then I made a blueprint based on that class. What should I do now?

I can get reference to image `MaterialInstanceConstant'/Game/Materials/Faces/mi_dialog_2.mi_dialog_2'`, but how to put it to image component of the blueprint?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The variable ***widgetDialogBottomInstance*** should be of type ***UDialogBottomWidget*** rather than the generic ***UUserWidget***. By having the proper type for both the variable and the *CreateWidget* function template parameter, you'll be able access the *SetImage* function you wrote:

```
UDialogBottomWidget* widgetDialogBottomInstance;
... 
widgetDialogBottomInstance = CreateWidget<UDialogBottomWidget>(GetWorld(), widgetDialogBottom);
widgetDialogBottomInstance->SetImage(...); // You can call SetImage here
```

Cheers!